# Build Nested Request Structure in Rspec controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, json-api, fabrication-gem

Currently i am working on a project that follows [json-api](http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-creating) standards.

My question here is what is the elegant and clean way of building nested `json-api` request strucutres for controller tests using `rspec`